# error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/asio.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I use Qt creator in windows 7. When I use 32-bit VC 2010 complier to complie my project, error occurs:
     error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/asio.hpp': No such file or 
     directory

.pro:

```
LIBS += -L"D:/MDT/boost_1_71_0/libs" - 
   llibboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x32-1_71 \
    - 
    L"D:/MDT/boost_1_71_0/libs" - 
    llibboost_regex-vc141-mt-x32-1_71 \
```

main.cpp

```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to tell the compiler where to look for the include files.

Add

`INCLUDEPATH += <path_to_boost_dir>`

to the .pro file. In your case it will probably be

`INCLUDEPATH += D:/MDT/boost_1_71_0/`

Comment: I have used your method and my problem fixed, but another occurs: asio.hpp:20: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp': No such file or directory

Comment: @williamYUANG, are you by chance including it like `#include "boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp"` instead of `#include <boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp>`? If this is not the case, check that the file actually exists. For example, for me it is in 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Boost\boost\asio\associated_allocator.hpp'. In this case the INCLUDEPATH should be `C:\Users\Username\Documents\Boost`, and the include directive should look like `#include <boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp>`

Comment: mine is #include <boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp>   and all the file exist in boost library. I did not change anything in the boost library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [INCLUDEPATH](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath) to specify where the libraries headers are, so you need to add: `INCLUDEPATH += D:/MDT/boost_1_71_0/` in your `.pro` file and run qmake.

But the `msvc141` (in boost lib names) stands for Visual Studio 2017 and that is not binary compatible with Visual Studio 2010 that you are using, so you will most likely get linker errors or weird run-time crashes. To fix that you need to download boost built with Visual Studio 2010, look for `msvc10` (32 or 64 bit depending on your needs) on the website where you downloaded boost and get that version.

Comment: I have used your method and my problem fixed, but another occurs: asio.hpp:20: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp': No such file or directory